# SCCM Wireless Adapter driver version info

Tags: sccm

iam working on SCCM Dashboard to get all wireless devices on whole SCCM, so iam running this query

```
    select count(name0),Name0 from v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER where
v_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER.Description0 like '%Wireless%' 
group by Name0
```

after running this query i do get wireless adapter list like this

[image]

my question is iam making pie chart to show this.. but i need Wifi driver Versions so  that i can show in drill down report for each model, so from where can i get Driver versions of Each model?

Comment: SCCM doesn't inventory information about drivers afaik so you would have to expand the whole inventory. It is possible (described e.g. at: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/configmgr_geek_speak/inventorying-and-reporting-network-adapter-driver-details-and-how-to-report-only-the-wireless-type-with-bonus-mini-primer-on-sql-report-builder-in-configuration-manager-2012) but not trivial. Alternative way could be to use the information about installed software if the driver is in addprograms but the relations would probably have to be hardcoded because those drivers names are arbitrary.

Comment: neways we raised called with MS.. only option is to Add PNP driver data once you add PNP driver view builts up.

Answer (score 0):

neways we raised called with MS.. only option is to Add PNP driver data once you add PNP driver view builts up.
we need to class to Default settings in client setting of SCCM